# Xcode 15 building failure when using iphone 15 as simulator, using ios 17

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, ios17

i have build my ios app using xcode 14 and ios 16.0.1, but some users report that app crashed on iphone 15 pro max, i assumed that it a version mismatch, i installed the last update available in app store for xcode, which is xcode 15, i installed ios 17, but when i try to build my app using iphone 15 i always got module not found : No such module 'Toast_Swift'.

i have removed toast_swift, but new module not found : No such module error occurs with SwiftyJSON,
i have tried to change and update the architecture by adding new build rules but does not help.